# run composer.phar install from elsewhere

Tags: symfony, composer-php, open-basedir

I need to run `composer.phar` install at the `/public/website/examplewebstie.com/dev.examplewebsite.com/examplewebsite/`.

But my server has an `open_basedir` restriction on levels higher than `/public/website/`.

Is there a way to run composer from `/public/website`, but have changes to take place in `/public/website/examplewebstie.com/dev.examplewebsite.com/examplewebsite/` 
(thats where i have my `composer.json`) without removing the `open_basedir` restriction?

Maybe a workaround with a symlink?

Comment: Can you go to 
`/public/website/examplewebstie.com/dev.examplewebsite.com/examplewebsite/` 
and run `php /public/composer.phar install` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
$ php composer.phar diagnose
```

first, if that succeeds without showing any issues, try running

```
$ php composer.phar install --working-dir /public/website/examplewebstie.com/dev.examplewebsite.com/examplewebsite
```

Looks like you have a typo in the path, though.

For reference, see

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#general
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options.